# InputField as part of a Graphics

Tags: graphics

I am building a model for which the user can enter parameter values. I would like to create a "graphical layout" of the model in which I display several InputField-s to enter the numerical parameters, arranged to be shown at the appropriate x-y-locations in my "graphical layout". However, InputFields appear to become non-editable when part of a Graphics object.

For example, the following works (of course):

```
InputField[Dynamic[x]]
```

However, the next command creates an InputField that cannot be accessed, although the dynamic value still correctly updates when you change the InputField created by the previous command:

```
Graphics[Inset[InputField[Dynamic[x]]]]
```

How can I place InputFields at specific coordinates in (or on top of) a Graphics?

Comment: @Nasser Yes, this seems to work. I have tried Graphics[...,Deployed->True], which does not work. Please, put it as an answer, then I can accept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Deploy@Graphics[Inset[InputField[Dynamic[x]]]]
```

Can be used to allow input to a field inside `Graphics`

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes `Text` is easier to place.

```
Deploy @ Graphics[{Circle[], Red, PointSize[Large], 
   Dynamic @ Point[{x, 0}], Text[InputField[Dynamic[x]], {0, 0.8}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

By the way, without the `Deploy`, you can edit the `InputField` this way.  Double-click over the `InputField`; then double-click again.  You should be able to edit the `InputField`.

Note: Without `Deploy` the user can edit the graphics, too.  Usually, with user interfaces, this undesirable.  In such cases you should use `Deploy` anyway.

Comment: Isn't `Text` implemented as `Inset` since version 6?  You can replace `Text` with `Inset` above and it behaves the same.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I did not know that.  The docs describe them differently (both arguments and function, which is only said to be "similar"), but, checking out combinations of arguments, they in fact they seem have the same syntax and semantics.  Thanks!  The docs made `Inset` harder for me to understand, and I've harbored a prejudice until now.  One instance: if the `Inset` argument `opos` had been described as well as `offset` for `Text`, it would have saved me trouble.  The argument `size` for `Inset`, omitted in the description for `Text`, does not always behave how I expect it.